# How can I apply a link over this entire div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a div on my home page that displays the 10 most popular products in my Woocommerce store.

HTML:

```
<div id="trending">
    <p class="trending-title">Trending Products</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="10" columns="5"]'); ?>
    <p class="please-scroll">*Please type in your delivery postcode in the search bar above to see the thousands of trending products available in you area.</p>
</div>
```

[image]

I do want users to purchase these products but I require them to type in their postcode first. I've removed the ability for the individual products to be clickable using the code:

```
#trending .woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now I want the whole div to be clickable to ONE link which is a redirect link for where users can type in their postcode and proceed. I've tried:

```
<a class="to-scroll" href="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/information">
    <div id="trending">
        <p class="trending-title">Trending Products</p>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="10" columns="5"]'); ?>
        <p class="please-scroll">*Please type in your delivery postcode in the search bar above to see the thousands of trending products available in you area.</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.to-scroll {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Does anybody have an insight into how I can create a sort of link overlay for the entire contents of this div to be clickable to ONE link?
Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: try to set `display: block` to your `a` the by css

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that in the code (I have now) but unfortunately it still doesn't work. @eisbehr

Comment: Your code works here to produce a clickable block: https://jsfiddle.net/rx5hrs1h/ -- Since you indicated WordPress is used, make sure your theme (or any other included stylesheets) are not overwriting your anchor tag style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create link inside div with class of ".trending". Redirects to that links value when anywhere in div is clicked.

```js
$(".trending").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="trending">
  Your content goes here.
  <a href="http://example.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added this code inbetween a set of script tags and placed it within my header.php file but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Most likely there might be overridden by your themes css you have to go over your theme documentation.

Comment: Any idea of what I should be keeping an eye it for? @GeraldBrigen

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could add a JS with JQuery like so:

```
$('#trending').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'http://the-url-you-want';
});
```

Comment: I've added this code inbetween a set of script tags and placed it within my header.php file but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Edited slightly - try now!

Answer (score 1):

So much jQuery in here...

[image]

That code works, you have other problems, test things in isolation before assuming that what you have already is broken.